# QWebSocket client doesn't connect to QWebSocketServer if server is set to not listen on creation and doesn't connect if server start to listen later

Tags: python, pyside6

**The problem**:
I want to make client to retry connection if server is unreachable by sending ping/text message using qtimer.
Client is expecting to get pong/text message from server to start processing some data.

Server is started without listening for incoming connection for first 20 seconds to imitate connection issue, and after 20 seconds i set server to listen so it can accept incoming connections.

If client can't connect to server in first attempt or during the 20 seconds period of not listening it will not connect even if server will start listening later, however if i run client when server switched to listening state everything will work. How i can i fix it so client will actually send ping/text message, because right now it looks like client is entering a loop, which prevents it from sending ping/text message.

Client part:

```
from time import sleep
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWebSockets
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication


class Client(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.client = QtWebSockets.QWebSocket("", QtWebSockets.QWebSocketProtocol.Version13, None)
        self.client.open(QUrl("ws://127.0.0.1:6000"))
        self.client.textMessageReceived.connect(self.process_message)
        self.client.pong.connect(self.get_pong)
        # self.client.error.connect(self.error)

        self.date_list = ['2000-01-01']

        self.check_status_timer = QTimer()
        self.check_status_timer.timeout.connect(self.send_ping)
        self.check_status_timer.start(2000)

    # some data processing after connection established
    def process(self, day):
        print(f"Day {day}")
        for i in range(10):
            print(f"Sleeping {9 - i}")
            sleep(.5)
        print("emitted")
        return True

    def create_and_run(self):
        current_date = self.date_list[0]
        result = self.process(current_date)
        if result:
            self.send_message()
        else:
            print("PROCESS FAILED")

    def process_message(self, message):
        if message == "ping" or message == "True":
            self.check_status_timer.stop()
            self.create_and_run()

    def get_pong(self):
        print("PONG")

    def send_ping(self):
        print("SENDING PING")
        self.client.ping()
        self.client.sendTextMessage("ping")

    def send_message(self):
        self.client.sendTextMessage("Client0")

    def error(self, error_code):
        print("error code: {}".format(error_code))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    client = Client(app)
    app.exec()
```

Server part

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWebSockets, QtNetwork
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication


class MyServer(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clients = []
        self.server = QtWebSockets.QWebSocketServer(parent.serverName(), parent.secureMode(), parent)
        self.server.acceptError.connect(self.on_accept_error)
        self.server.newConnection.connect(self.on_new_connection)
        
        # create timer so server will switch to listening state later
        self.count = 0
        self.timer_listen = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer_listen.timeout.connect(self.make_listen)
        self.timer_listen.start(2000)
    
    def make_listen(self):
        if self.count >= 10:
            self.timer_listen.stop()
            self.server.listen(QtNetwork.QHostAddress.LocalHost, 6000)
            print(self.count, self.server.isListening())
        else:
            print(self.count, self.server.isListening())
            self.count += 1

    def on_accept_error(accept_error):
        print("Accept Error: {}".format(accept_error))

    def on_new_connection(self):
        client_connection = self.server.nextPendingConnection()
        client_connection.textMessageReceived.connect(self.process_message)
        client_connection.disconnected.connect(self.disconnect)
        self.clients.append(client_connection)

    def process_message(self, message):
        print(message)
        if message == "ping":
            self.sender().sendTextMessage("ping")

    def disconnect(self):
        if self.sender() in self.clients:
            self.clients.remove(self.sender())
            self.sender().deleteLater()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    serverObject = QtWebSockets.QWebSocketServer('My Socket', QtWebSockets.QWebSocketServer.NonSecureMode)
    server = MyServer(serverObject)
    serverObject.closed.connect(app.quit)
    app.exec()
```

I tried to utilize worker class to prevent client's main loop to freeze, and i tried to subclass QWebsocket, but had no luck.

Comment: If the client didn't connect, there's no point trying to send anything because [the socket isn't valid](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebsocket.html#isValid). You need to keep calling `open` until the connection is made.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but unfortunately the behaviour is still the same, the only difference is i am getting `QNativeSocketEngine::write() was not called in QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState` error while server is not listening, and error disappears when server starts listening.

`pyside 6.6.2
python 3.8 (3.8.18 | packaged by conda-forge from sys.version)`

Comment: It all works perfectly fine for me. Obviously, I have no idea what you're doing wrong, since you've provided no code.

Comment: The only thing i've changed is moved `self.client.open(QUrl("ws://127.0.0.1:6000"))` from init to send_ping() function

Comment: Use something like `if self.client.state() ==
            QAbstractSocket.SocketState.ConnectedState: # do ping etc: else: # do open`.

Comment: you are absolutely right, this works! I will post a complete code in aswer and point to your solution, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per solution provided by [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) in [comment section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137283/qwebsocket-client-doesnt-connect-to-qwebsocketserver-if-server-is-set-to-not-li/78141888#comment137754232_78137283)

```
from time import sleep
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWebSockets
from PySide6.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtNetwork import QAbstractSocket

class Client(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.client = QtWebSockets.QWebSocket("", QtWebSockets.QWebSocketProtocol.Version13, None)

        self.client.textMessageReceived.connect(self.process_message)
        self.client.pong.connect(self.get_pong)
        # self.client.error.connect(self.error)

        self.date_list = ['2000-01-01']

        self.check_status_timer = QTimer()
        self.check_status_timer.timeout.connect(self.send_ping)
        self.check_status_timer.start(2000)

    def process(self, day):
        print(f"Day {day}")
        for i in range(10):
            print(f"Sleeping {9 - i}")
            sleep(.5)
        print("emitted")
        return True

    def create_and_run(self):
        current_date = self.date_list[0]
        result = self.process(current_date)
        if result:
            self.send_message()
        else:
            print("PROCESS FAILED")

    def process_message(self, message):
        if message == "ping" or message == "True":
            self.check_status_timer.stop()
            self.create_and_run()

    def get_pong(self):
        print("PONG")

    def send_ping(self):
        print("SENDING PING")
        if self.client.state() == QAbstractSocket.SocketState.ConnectedState:
            self.client.ping()
            self.client.sendTextMessage("ping")
        else:
            self.client.open(QUrl("ws://127.0.0.1:6000"))


    def send_message(self):
        self.client.sendTextMessage("Client0")

    def error(self, error_code):
        print("error code: {}".format(error_code))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    client = Client(app)
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Although this "fixes" your example, it isn't really robust. A much better solution would be to use the built-in signals of the websocket to wait until the connection is made before attempting to communicate with the server. This would entail creating a simple `connect` method that called `client.open`, and in the `error` slot  adding `if QAbstractSocket.ConnectionRefusedError: QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.connect)`. Then you'd add `self.client.connected.connect(self.send_ping); self.connect()` to `__init__`. This approach will eliminate the need for  `check_status_timer`.

Comment: Yeah, that's even better. Thank you!